# Multiple URL to the same page with with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I like to point different url to the same single page html.
The rewrite rule will happen only if a keyword exist in the incoming URL.

This is an example:

Actual URL: https://example.com/folder/page. This is the html page to show.

Let say the keyword is ‘hello’.
hello is not a folder or a file in the server.

So when I enter https://example.com/folder/page/hello into the browser

URL will be https://example.com/folder/page/hello but it returns content from https://example.com/folder/page without changing the browser url.

How can i achieve this using htaccess?

I have something like this but its not working. Not sure if I'm in the right direction

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} hello
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder/$1/$2 !-d   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: "A keyword"?  You need to be more explicit.  If you always want to redirect `https://example.com/folder/page/xxxxx` for any xxxxx, that's easy.  As long as you have `page.php` at the `folder` level, Apache will do that automatically.  No extra .htaccess is required.  Just the lines to handle mapping `page` to `page.php`.

Comment: @TimRoberts sorry I think my question itself is very confusing. I'm not even sure if it can be done. I have edited the question and hope its clearer.

Comment: Right, that's what I said.  Apache goes through each step in a URL until it finds a matching page.  It will check to see if `folder` has a handler.  In your case, it will be a directory, so it goes into that directory and looks for `page`.  With your .htaccess, it finds `page.php` and runs that to handle the request, passing `"/hello"` in the `PATH_INFO` environment variable.  You don't need any rewrite magic, this is a feature of CGI.

Comment: @TimRoberts This is only true if `MultiViews` are enabled (which often causes multiple other issues). And the implementation the OP posted certainly will _not_ achieve what is asked.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like that?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} hello
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/[^/]+/[^/]+)/?
RewriteCond %1.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+/[^/]+)/? /$1.php [L]
```

This would implement the logic for all combinations of a "folder" and a "page" if a file `/<folder>/<page>.php` exists and the keyword "hello" exists further down the requested path.

**Update**

The solution above didn't work perfectly but a little tweak and it works now. Thank you @arkascha.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} hello
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/[^/]+/[^/]+)/?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+/[^/]+)/? /$1.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: thank you for your input. Your solution didnt work perfectly. I did a little change and it worked. 

Thanks

Comment: @user3126531 You removed the check for the existence of the php file, why? And why should it be necessary to check if the requested path points to a file or folder? In your question you wrote: " is not a folder or a file in the server.". So that is not true and it actually is? Also in your question you said nothing about that you require an additional dynamic property "page". As @TimRoberts already correctly pointed out in his comments to the question you could simply get that information from the `PATH_INFO` environment variable.